# Dynamically Load JS in "Head" using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I am working on my own custom CMS that allows me to create tiny block of codes and place them across the site - something that Joomla does as well. What i want to do is that each block of code might have its own JS files that are related to just that block. So i want to dynamically add the JS into the head tag using PHP. Now i found this solution on the net and created a class for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "/path/to/pikachoosejs/jquery.pikachoose.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Here's the PHP version:

```
<?php function loadcss($path) { ?>
<script>
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "<?php echo $path; ?>";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Now here is the problem, If i add this code, it does include it in the Head Tag. But, somehow the Pikachoose doesnt work. If i do a normal include using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/pikachoosejs/jquery.pikachoose.js"> </script>
```

Heres the PHP function that I use to call the script -

it does work fine. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Where is PHP in there?

Comment: try jquery's [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky - skipped that part cause it really didnt make showing a php function that has the exact same thing as the javascript. Anyways, adding it now.

Comment: @gwillie - how do i use this to append the getScript to head tag? I can use it to load JS in the body, but I want to push it to the head tag.

Comment: well i've never worried about where it inserts it. if you really want in `<head>` then jQuery it,
`$('head').append("<script src='somescript.js' type='text/javascript'></script>");`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(function () { 
var li = document.createElement('script'); 
li.type = 'text/javascript'; 
li.src= "<?php echo $path; ?>";
li.async=true;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(li, s); 
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is writing a `script` tag somewhere into your HTML, depending on where your function is called. It differs greatly from Joomla! especially since it relies on the client to append the script to the head.

In order to do something Joomla!-ish, you'll need to work with the [output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php), or maybe a server-side equivalent of jQuery, like [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/).

For a simple case like yours, I'd use *phpQuery* as it makes things a lot easier for a jQuery coder.

---

**A simple setup for your mini CMS** could be like this. At its beginning, but the following, and do not use any HTML in your code unless you explicitly intend to.

```
phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('/path/to/template.html');
```

It creates a new context for phpQuery by loading a template file into its memory and is **required**, but can be one of different variations. See the [Basics documentation](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Basics).

**Function to append scripts:**

```
function loadJS( $name ) {
    pq('<script>')->attr('src', $name)->appendTo('head');
}
```

Nearly all methods available in jQuery are available in phpQuery as well. The only exception I've found so far is the `css` method, since it is impossible to know which styles will be rendered on client side without in-depth analysis of the linked stylesheets.

**Finally, to write the DOM** to your response:

```
echo pq('html');
```

---

Whether it is your current approach or this one, the `jquery.pikachoose.js` script actually should work. Check your resources in your Developer Tools to see if it has been loaded. If so, check out if there were any errors related to your script that prevented it from loading up properly as a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the script to be generated by PHP, you need to put it in a PHP file. Rename the file to js/getdata.js.php and update the src accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An other short simple and reliable way to do this is save the script tag string in a variable like.

```
<?php function loadcss($path) { ?>

     $sc = "<script type='text/javascript' src='$path'></script>"; ?>
     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<?php echo $sc ?>';

<?php } ?>
```

Consider two things that you are getting correct path. You have really a head tag. If yes then use following code.

This code should be correct but if you do not get it working... To make sure that this code is correct.. you can Inspect your head element (with firebug) and you will see. script node would have been writeen using this code

Answer (score 0):

```
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'http://xxx./yyy.js';
document.getelementsbytagname('head')[0].appendChild();
```

I think this is the best one.